# SIM 808 Module, ERROR message after AT + CMGS command

Tags: gsm, at-command

I am trying to send SMS via a SIM 808 GSM Module. After using AT+CMEE = 1, I am getting CMS `+CMS ERROR: 604`. 
AT + CMGL command is working fine but I am still not able to send SMS. 
Here's the code :

```
#include<msp430.h> 
void sms()
{
Serial.println("AT\r");
delay(1000);
Serial.println("AT+CMGF = 1\r");
delay(1000);
Serial.println("AT+CMGL = \"ALL\"\r");
Serial.println("AT+CMEE = 1\r");
Serial.println(" AT+CMGS =\"+91xxxxxxxxxx\"\r");
delay(1000);
Serial.println("HELLO WORLD");
delay(1000);
Serial.println((char)26);
delay(100);
}
void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
   sms();
}

void loop(){

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tested the code below. It worked. It was the \r's.
Shorter delays ok..

```
Serial.println("AT");
delay(50);
Serial.println("AT+CMGF=1");
delay(50);
Serial.println("AT+CMEE=1");
delay(50);
Serial.println("AT+CMGS=\"1xxxxxxxxxx\"");
delay(50);
Serial.println("HELLO WORLD");
delay(50);
Serial.println((char)26);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am looking into your issues.  First, and possibly the basis of all issues, you do not need the \r in a println.

Serial.println("AT+CMEE = 1") is proper way to send to SIM 808.  I have a sim 808 online and will test what you have.  I have just mastered the SMS world with my SIM 808 so this won't take long.
dy3